# How can matter exist without electric charge?

Tags: particle-physics, charge, standard-model, quarks

I read in a textbook that that matter CAN exist without charge. But quarks, the fundamental constituent of matter itself contains charge, up quark has +2/3 charge and down quark has -1/3 charge so then the former sentence shouldn't be true. Where is this going wrong?

Comment: What textbook says that and what is the context of the statement? Is it talking about macroscopic matter or basic particles?

Comment: idk i just got confused, the question in the textbook was - charge cannot exist without matter although matter can exist without charge (true or false). this statement is true but i didnt understand how cause even the fundamental constituent of matter doesnt exist without charge.
where am i wrong?

Comment: Tanya, if you got the question wrong, please edit it, or delete and post a new question.

Comment: i didnt get the question wrong, this is exactly what i wanted to ask. im just way too confused.

Comment: Again, what is the context? Macroscopic matter (i.e., baseballs, apple pie, etc) or standard model particles? Is it a lower level physical science text or a graduate level text?

Comment: im in highschool (12th grade), and i didnt study bout quarks or similar thing in school i read this on wikipedia. and this question is from electrostatics and it said matter CAN exist without charge. 
Do answer in a way that satisfies a highschool kid that doesnt have too much knowledge of university texts.

Comment: If we one day discover an elementary particle which is neutral, we can imagine forming matter out of it the way we form matter out of quarks. Whereas if we detect charge in a region, there must be some matter there which carries that charge. This is probably what the book is trying to say but it sounds like a bad book.

Comment: so, any matter will ALWAYS have some charge on it is what you mean to say?

Comment: No. I said and meant to say that matter not carrying charge (whether or not we've discovered any) is easy to conceive of. Charge existing without there being matter to carry it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read in a textbook that that matter CAN exist without charge. But quarks, the fundamental constituent of matter itself contains charge, up quark has +2/3 charge and down quark has -1/3 charge so then the former sentence shouldn't be true. Where is this going wrong?

Not all matter is made of quarks. The standard model has "three generations of matter", and note in particular that the bottom row of leptons is composed of particles with no charge called neutrinos.

[image]